# Getting the clicked view in a multi-view listItem and the correct data - Using ListView, CursorAdapter

Tags: android, onclicklistener, android-cursoradapter, onitemclicklistener

So I have a CursorAdapter that I am using for my listview. I want each list item to have 4 clickable views, because I will have different things happen when each thing is clicked... not important here.

[image: listview items]

**My problem...** is that I am not able to get both the data in a selected item (or row) and the view (1 through 4) that was clicked inside that list item.

**What I've tried so far:**

1. When I override onClick in my CursorAdapter I can get the view
   successfully, but then returning the data for that list item is not
   correct (it returns the data from only the first entry in the list
   no matter what has been selected).
2. So I tried implementing onItemClick in the activity that hosts the listview. When I do this
   I am able to get the data from which ever item was selected but then
   I can not get one of the four clickable areas from the list item.
3. When I try to use both of these ideas the onClick override in the
   CursorAdapter seems to override the onItemClick method in the
   activity and then all I can do is get the correct view (1 of 4) that
   was selected in the list item.

Perhaps one of these strategies is the right one and I am just not either getting the data the correct way or getting the view correctly. Regardless, any help would be appreciated!

**When implementing the onClick from my CursorAdapter:**

```
@Override
public void bindView(View v, Context context, Cursor c) {
    ImageView imPlay = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.row_play_button);
    LinearLayout llFirstHalf = (LinearLayout) v.findViewById(R.id.row_first_half);
    LinearLayout llSecondHalf = (LinearLayout) v.findViewById(R.id.row_second_half);
    CheckBox cbCheck = (CheckBox) v.findViewById(R.id.row_checkbox);

}


public void myOnClick(View v) {
    switch(v.getId()){

    case R.id.row_checkbox:
        //do something
        break;
    case R.id.row_first_half:
        //do something
        break;
    case R.id.row_second_half:
        //do something
        break;
    case R.id.row_play_button:
        //do something
        break;
```

**When implementing the onItemClick in MainActivity:**

```
@Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int index, long pos) {
    Log.e("onITEMCLICK",    "index: "+String.valueOf(index));
    Log.e("onITEMCLICK",    "position: "+String.valueOf(pos));
    LinearLayout listItem = (LinearLayout) view;


    String title;
    String date_created;
    String comments;
    String sample_rate;
    String duration;
    String file_size;
    String id;
    String file_url;

    Cursor c = app.rec_adapter.getCursor();
    c.moveToPosition(index);
    title = c.getString(c.getColumnIndexOrThrow(DBAdapter.rKEY_TITLE));
    date_created = c.getString(c.getColumnIndexOrThrow(DBAdapter.rKEY_DATE_CREATED));
    comments = c.getString(c.getColumnIndexOrThrow(DBAdapter.rKEY_COMMENTS));
    sample_rate = c.getString(c.getColumnIndexOrThrow(DBAdapter.rKEY_SAMPLE_RATE));
    sample_rate = convertToHumanReadable(sample_rate);
    duration = c.getString(c.getColumnIndexOrThrow(DBAdapter.rKEY_DURATION));
    file_size = c.getString(c.getColumnIndexOrThrow(DBAdapter.rKEY_FILE_SIZE));
    file_url = c.getString(c.getColumnIndexOrThrow(DBAdapter.rKEY_FILE_URL));
    id = c.getString(c.getColumnIndexOrThrow(DBAdapter.rKEY_ROWID));


// find out what section was clicked on the item -- NO SOLUTION
    ImageView imPlay = (ImageView) listItem.findViewById(R.id.row_play_button);
    LinearLayout llFirstHalf = (LinearLayout) listItem.findViewById(R.id.row_first_half);
    LinearLayout llSecondHalf = (LinearLayout) listItem.findViewById(R.id.row_second_half);
    CheckBox cbCheck = (CheckBox) listItem.findViewById(R.id.row_checkbox);



}
```

Comment: you have this `LinearLayout listItem = (LinearLayout) view;` so you have initialized using `listItem`. I thought you need to get the data from the row items. and you already have the views initialized. so what is the problem in getting data?

Comment: Please don't prefix your questions titles with Android, the tag at the bottom is more than enough. As you need to watch for clicked events on the four views from a row you can't use `onItemClick()` because that gets triggered when the entire row is clicked. Instead you should set the `onClick` listeners for the four views(in `bindView()`) and pass them the `cursor.getPosition()` value as a tag. This way you'll know the row in the `ListView`  where this view was clicked so you can retrieve the proper data.

Comment: Ok thanks for the tip. So for each clickable view I'll be setting it's tag to the current cursor position? Then when I wanna get the row info I'll have to do a 'pos =view.getTag()' , set the cursor to pos, and then 'cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow()' to get my data? @Luksprog

Comment: one problem... when i do the getTag to the cursor position it keeps giving me only the first item position. I do this with: `View parent = v.getRootView();` `View vId = (View)parent.findViewById(R.id.row_id); int cursor_pos = (Integer) vId.getTag();`
  
      Cursor mCursor = this.c;
      mCursor.moveToPosition(cursor_pos);'

Comment: ha solved my own problem. Instead of using `v.getRootView(); I needed to use v.getParent();` I guess the getRootView(); got the Listview layout and then just took the first R.id.row_id view, which was always the first item... makes sense